How would you derive the Copenhagen interpretation rules from the many-worlds theory?
I have a real problem with understanding this one. Suppose you are taught in some school, without access to experiments, just theory, the many-worlds interpretation of physics. So that's all you have, and now you go out into the world. How would you be able to derive the various rules such as the Born rule that the probability of a wave function is the square of the wave function.  Or how would you derive the principle of measurement causing a wave collapse?
It's not clear to me if all you know is the multiworld hypothesis, how you obtain the real world observations.  To me it seems like you have these wave functions, and it's not clear where you figure out what we see as wave collapse, since there is no such thing as collapse in the multi world hypothesis, or even if you need probabilities, since with infinite worlds with infinite possibilities, does squaring the wave function even matter?
I know you should be able to do this as the theories physically are equivalent, yet I'm not sure how you derive the copenhagen postulates if you start with only the many worlds hypothesis.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/492082 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133906 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/622860

Also (possibly more strongly) related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/762350

If you could derive one interpretation from another, they wouldn't be called alternative interpretations.

Anywhere that teaches basic quantum theory without referencing experiment would be a very poor learning environment for physics, which is, by definition, grounded by experiment.

In relation to what WillO wrote, indeed I think that when OP writes "Copenhagen postulates" they mean the QM postulates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics#Postulates_of_quantum_mechanics

" infinite worlds with infinite possibilities" Each measurement has a finite number of possible findings in the Copenhagen interpretation and the same number of worlds in MWI, so shouldn't the probabilities mean essentially the same thing in the two interpretations?

The MWI is what you get if you take the equations of motion of quantum theory and work out its implications as one would for any other physical theory.
You ask:

Or how would you derive the principle of measurement causing a wave collapse?

You wouldn't since collapse is incompatible with the equations of motion of quantum theory.
Instead you would notice that classical physics describes the evolution of a measurable quantity such as the $x$ position of a particle by a function $x(t)$ whose value at time $t$ is the result you would get if you measured the $x$ position.
In quantum physics a measurable quantity is described by a Hermitian matrix called an observable. The possible results of measuring that quantity are the eigenvalues of the observable and quantum theory predicts the expectation value of the observable. In general that expectation value will depend on what happens to all of the possible values during the experiment: this is called quantum interference, see Section 2 of this paper for an example:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
When information is copied out of a quantum system interference is suppressed - this is called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
Decoherence doesn't eliminate the different possible values (i.e. - collapse) it makes them unable to interact with one another so they evolve autonomously. The end result of this is that reality as described by quantum theory looks approximately like a collection of parallel universes in the circumstances of everyday life:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
Decoherence doesn't totally eliminate interference so how you slice up reality into universes isn't exact. In practice two versions of you sitting one millimetre apart won't undergo interference so they are independent, although the electrons in atoms in your body are still undergoing interference on scales of about $10^{-10}m$.
There are a couple of different approaches to understanding probability in quantum theory without collapse. One is to say that the probability of an outcome is a function of the state that satisfies particular properties required by decision theory, like if a person uses those probabilities you can't make him take a series of bets that will make him lower the expectation value of his winnings, the probability of an outcome can't be changed by a later measurement and some other assumptions
https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2718
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0303050
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906015
https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02048
Another approach called envariance looks at invariant features of the joint state of a quantum system entangled with the environment and using that to work out probabilities using the ignorance interpretation of probability:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405161
I should also note that quantum theory with collapse isn't equivalent to quantum theory without collapse since the equations of motion of quantum theory don't include collapse, claims to the contrary notwithstanding. Some physicists have tried to change the equations of motion of quantum theory to include collapse:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
These theories don't currently reproduce the predictions of relativistic quantum field theories which are the vast bulk of experimentally tested predictions of quantum theory:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
Collapse also doesn't describe most measurements, e.g. - it doesn't describe repeated, continuous or unsharp measurements:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05973
