# Does the Many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics imply the existence of all conceivable worlds?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, quantum-interpretations, quantum-states, multiverse

what I mean by this is, does every universe conceivable exist? would any universe i think of exist? could there be a universe of nothingness? are there universes of TV shows? are there universes with different laws of physics? constants? forces? math?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "exist". They do exist in your imagination.They don't exist as our physical observables.

Comment: Asking if there are _universes with different laws of physics?_ seems like an invitation to non-mainstream/opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the Many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics imply the existence of all conceivable worlds?

It all hinges on the words **interpretation**, and **existence.**

Interpretation, as used in physics,  means an alternative mathematical model that explains the same observations and measurements, and also is equally successful in predictions. For example, for the non relativistic case , [Bohmian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory) is an interpretation of the observations  that are perfectly modeled with non relativistic quantum  mechanics. It is a more complicated mathematically model, but it works because in a deterministic model gives the results of probabilistic non relativistic quantum mechanics

Existence, as used in physics, means observations and measurements.

So even if Bohmian mechanics explains and predicts the same data, there is no way to "see" the intricate pilot waves it needs to get at the same results as non relativistic quantum mechanics.

The many worlds interpretation is actually postulating that the [path integral method of quantum field theory, :](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation)

> The path integral formulation of quantum mechanics is a description of quantum theory that generalizes the action principle of classical mechanics. It replaces the classical notion of a single, unique classical trajectory for a system with a sum, or functional integral, over an infinity of quantum-mechanically possible trajectories to compute a quantum amplitude.

generates a universe for each vertex in the formulation. I.e., it takes the mathematics literally.

The mathematics exists and is the same, whether one interprets it in the mainstream QFT  , or interpreting as "many worlds branching off" . *But there is no way to call the paths into an existence other than mathematical, and keep being an interpretation* by the definition of interpretation in physics.

Once one assumes an existence it stops being mainstream physics and becomes metaphysics; (unless it makes predictions for experiments and data that are different than the predictions of the path integral method, and can be measured experimentally; which has not happened) .